# Haystack No site conf error . How to debug?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I checked every single possible places that this error might be caused but not able to get to what to do . 
This is my settings.py

```
# Django global settings

# This allows us to construct the needed absolute paths dynamically,
# e.g., for the GIS_DATA_DIR, MEDIA_ROOT, and TEMPLATE_DIRS settings.
# see: http://rob.cogit8.org/blog/2008/Jun/20/django-and-relativity/
import os
GEOGRAPHIC_ADMIN_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#id1
# Your user must be a postgrest superuser
# Avoid specifying your password with: ~/.pgpass
# http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html
T    EST_RUNNER='django.contrib.gis.tests.run_gis_tests'

DEBUG=True

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'postgresql_psycopg2'
DATABASE_NAME = 'geoadmin'
DATABASE_USER = 'postgres' # make sure to change this to your postgres user
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_HOST = ''
DATABASE_PORT = ''

# Not used at this point but you'll need it here if you 
# want to enable a google maps baselayer within your
# OpenLayers maps
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY='abcdefg'

SHP_UPLOAD_DIR = r"/home/satyajit/geodjango/geographic_admin/data"
GIS_DATA_DIR = os.path.join(GEOGRAPHIC_ADMIN_DIR, 'data')

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Vancouver'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(GEOGRAPHIC_ADMIN_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

HAYSTACK_SITECONF='geographic_admin.search_sites'

HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'xapian'
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = '/home/satyajit/geodjango/geographic_admin/xapian-index'


ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'
SECRET_KEY = '2f!vq4!f)u#g-sk7_=z+i0e(o0o&hue5khxbdkdx$f%hvpb^vd'
LOGIN_URL='/accounts/login/'
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)

from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
     'django.core.context_processors.request',
     'django.core.context_processors.debug',
     'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
     'django.core.context_processors.media',
     'django.core.context_processors.static',
     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

) 
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'userprofile.profile'
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/satyajit/geodjango/geographic_admin/sitestatic"

if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(GEOGRAPHIC_ADMIN_DIR, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(GEOGRAPHIC_ADMIN_DIR, '../registration/templates'),

    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.databrowse',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'world',
    'maps',
    'shapes',
    'registration',
    'waypoints',
    'openmaps',
    'permissions',
    'floppyforms',
    'OsmMap',
    'userprofile',
    'mapsearch',
    'haystack',

)

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS=7
EMAIL_HOST='localhost'
EMAIL_PORT=1023
EMAIL_HOST_USER='username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
```

The error I get is this

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('The HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting is no longer used & can be removed.')
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting is no longer used & can be removed.
```

So I removed SITECONF from settings.py
and the error I get is this

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE setting has been replaced with HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS.
```

What can be the problem ?

I am utterly stuck .

Comment: I hope you changed your secret key some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you have django-haystack v. 1.2.x settings and are running django-haystack 2.x

I would either revert back to running your previous version of django-haystack, or rewrite the `HAYSTACK_*` parts of your `settings.py` file using the how to migrate from 1.2 to 2.0 [documentation](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-haystack/en/latest/migration_from_1_to_2.html).

Also - if you want to roll back your django-haystack git repo to the 1.2.4 version, just issue (in the repo)

```
git reset --hard v1.2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the HayStack Versions. This is the Latest Version [Docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/tutorial.html#configuration)(1.2.7) which supports HAYSTACK_SITECONF